# SQL Server query select a row of the table where 2 conditions must be true

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 6 columns

```
No, Id, Created, Snapshot, Note, Size
```

Please see the screenshot to understand the table structure.

[image]

I want to select the row where **Note** Like "default" and the **No** has the maximum value. Please note that Note could contain several same values like "default"

It might be a very basic question. But asked already. But I couldn't find any that works for me. So far I tried:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mytable
WHERE Note = 'defalut' AND No = (SELECT MAX(No) FROM Mytable)
```

I got no result. Please let me know how to get it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mytable
WHERE Note = 'default' AND No = (SELECT MAX(No) FROM Mytable WHERE Note = 'default')
```

Comment: thanks it works perfectly. Actually, it works for all the given answer. Since I have to do this query form C# code that is why I  mark as answer the most simple answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `Max Over()` window function

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               MaxNo = Max(No)OVER()
        FROM   Mytable
        WHERE  Note = 'default') a
WHERE  No = MaxNo
```

Comment: thanks it works perfectly. Actually, it works for all the given answer. Since I have to do this query form C# code that is why I will mark as answer the most simple answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in this case to get the largest `No`

```
SELECT  No, Id, Created, Snapshot, Note, Size
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  *,
                RN = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY No DESC)
        FROM    MyTable
        WHERE   Note = 'default'
    ) a
WHERE RN = 1
```

However, if `No` is unique for all rows, you can just remove add `Note` filter in subquery

```
SELECT No, Id, Created, Snapshot, Note, Size
FROM   Mytable
WHERE  No = (SELECT MAX(No) FROM Mytable WHERE Note = 'default')
```

Comment: I believe that you should use `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`. Since this solution will omit rows if there is more than one with the same maximum `No` value.

Comment: thanks it works perfectly. Actually, it works for all the given answer. Since I have to do this query form C# code that is why I will mark as answer the most simple answer. Thanks a lot.